# Is one NFC device capable of answer to a P2P without tapping the phone again?

Tags: ssl, p2p, tap

Is the following scenario possible on P2P communication with NFC: Tap Device1 to Device2 pushing something within an app (which is also installed on Device 2) and Device2 capable of answer within the app without having the need to tap them again?

Another question: P2P mode is not encrypted, right? Is it possible to create some sort of communication with SSL/TSL applied to P2P?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question is NO if you're strictly talking about android. Android does not allow users to send NFC beams unless they use the touch to beam functionality for security reasons and unfortunately there is no other way around it.

The answer to the second question is you could always encrypt the data that you are encapsulating without the support of the P2P protocols. As for security in general, the IETF is working on LLCPS which improves LLCP using TLS. But it's still in development.